# Assets in a Matrix can't select files from a subfolder

Tags: matrix, assets

*EDIT: Nevermind - case of outdated indexes. Could really use a warning when this happens though...*

EE 2.8.1, Assets 2.3.1, Matrix 2.5.10

I've got a Matrix field with an Assets column, which is restricted to a specific Upload Destination. Said destination has subfolders. When I select a file from the Upload Destination folder itself, things work as expected. However, when I select a file from one of the subfolders, nothing appears to register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, for some reason, the Assets index was outdated for that folder, showing a weird mixture of old and current folders and files. I'm still not sure I'm ok with the ease at which both EE and Assets' indexes get out of sync without warning, but a re-indexing resolved the issue. Sorry for the false alarm.